# C++ classes - how to reference a member function from another member function

Tags: c++, oop, class, member-functions

I'm very new to c++ classes, so this is probably a really obvious question, but because I'm not familiar with the lingo yet I cant seem to be able to get a correct search term.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is have a public function in a class access a private function in same class.

eg

```
//.h file:

class foo {

float useful(float, float);

public:

int bar(float);

};

//.cpp file:

int foo::useful(float a, float b){
//does something and returns an int
}

int foo::bar(float a){
//how do I access the 'useful' function in foo?? eg something like
return useful(a, 0.8); //but this doesnt compile
}
```

Comment: You can use `this->useful(a, 0.8);` as well. But you need to correct the type of your function declaration first.

Comment: GAHH so sorry to waste anyone's time; I simply had a typo. The error it gave me was 'function not declared in this scope' so I thought I had a syntax error. newbie fail

Comment: everyone hits these kinds of problems. Its more embarrassing when you start getting better and find yourself get tripped up by something like this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return types don't match:

```
//.h file:

class foo {

float useful(float, float);      // <--- THIS ONE IS FLOAT ....

public:

int bar(float);

};

//.cpp file:

int foo::useful(float a, float b){       // <-- ...THIS ONE IS INT. WHICH ONE?
//does something and returns an int
}

int foo::bar(float a){
//how do I access the 'useful' function in foo?? eg something like
return useful(a, 0.8); //but this doesnt compile
}
```

The compiler looks for a function definition that matches exactly. The compiler error that you are getting is probably complaining about the fact that it a) can't find `float useful()`, or b) doesn't know what you mean when you're talking about `int useful`.

Make sure those match, and calling `useful` within `bar` should work just fine.

Comment: Ill accept your answer because it is a good answer because it highlights another error

Answer (score 2):

The function `useful` is declared to return a `float`, but you define it as returning an `int`.

Contrast

```
float useful(float, float);
```

vs

```
int foo::useful(float a, float b){
    //does something and returns an int
}
```

If you change the declaration to `int useful(float, float)` and return something from the function it will work fine.

Comment: Oh oops, thats just a demo I threw together to explain what I am after

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the error message your compiler gives you, I'll take a guess.  The return types of `useful()` don't match in the .h and .cpp files.  If you make them match (both int or both float) everything should work as you expect.